# Трансляция звука

Tags: аудио, звукозапись

Подскажите программу, чтобы она транслировала звук речь в реальном времени. То есть, нужно установить такую программу на ПК, чтобы я мог подключиться к нему удаленно и слушать что говорят там и т.д. Программа должна запускаться в фоне вместе с системой и работать тоже в фоне. Существуют ли такие программы?

Comment: Вам нужна программа для скрытного подслушивания?

Comment: а видео писать в фоне скрытно не надо?

Comment: Напиши стриминговый сервер на php или python, размести его на хостинге в интернете, затем напиши клиента на c++, java или delphi (да вообще на чем угодно), который будет транслировать звук на твой сервер, и слушай. А насчет того есть ли такие программы не знаю, но есть ip-камеры, через них не только слушать можно, но и подсматривать)

Comment: Поставил VLC , он позволяет прослушку вести

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант - "ivideon server" . Работает как служба, пишет и транслирует видео и звук. Бесплатна, если не считать облачное хранение. Есть некоторая нестабильность в работе при определенных условиях.

Vlc запущенный с определенными параметрами и транслировать звук например по rtsp и слушать другим vlc в локальной сети. Просто кинуть ярлык с параметрами в автозагрузку

Comment: Попробую, спасибо